# DefinitelyTyped for systemjs-builder

Tags: node.js, typescript, systemjs, definitelytyped

Is there a DefinitelyTyped for systemjs-builder?
https://github.com/systemjs/builder

Because systemjs.d.ts does not seem to include it, and I get a "cannot find module" error when I try to import it:

```
import Builder = require('systemjs-builder');
```

And I couldn't find a systemjs-builder.d.ts file on the internet.

If there isn't a DefinitelyTyped for that library, how can I use it with TypeScript?

Any help will be profoundly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/systemjs/systemjs.d.ts should includes Type definifions for the builder.

**edit:**
it seems like there are no typings avalible (maybe most use it with js). When you dont want to create the typings yourself you can put this in a `systemjs-builder.d.ts`:

```
declare module "systemjs-builder" {
  var builder: any;
  export = builder;
}
```

and write `/// <reference path="../yourpath/systemjs-builder.d.ts" />` in your main typings.

Comment: I have the same file, and I can't find the definitions for the builder in there, and I get the error I've written above. The only occurrence of the word "Builder" in this file is inside a comment. If it does contain the definitions, so what is wrong with my code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

To use in typescript you should import as follows:

```
import * as Builder from "systemjs-builder";
```

Then you can use

```
const builder = new Builder("", "systemjs.config.js");
builder.bundle("file.js", "output.js", {
    format: "cjs",
    minify: true,
    sourceMaps: true,
    mangle: false
});
```